Transforming (aggregating) network logs 14 million records every 5 min
I have 14 million records arriving every 5 minutes from Filebeat into a data stream (NetFlow data). My goal is to aggregate this data based on certain rules, such as summing source bytes and destination bytes for specific protocols. Here's the challenge:
Grouping: Data is grouped using a key (community.id) within 5-minute intervals.
Missing Data Issue:
The destination.bytes field in the source data is always empty.
I need to derive destination.bytes and destination.packets based on IP flow (e.g., bidirectional, unidirectional flows).
Volume and Velocity:
Handling this massive volume and velocity of data requires efficient transformation logic.
Elastic Feasibility:**
Can Elasticsearch handle this scale effectively?
How should I configure the transformation pipeline to achieve this aggregation reliably?
I'm running elastic on Azure , with 3 node setup
Transformation Configuration:
Below is the current transformation definition in Elasticsearch. It attempts to derive destination data (bytes and packets) from reverse flows, but I need advice on whether this approach is optimal and achievable for my use case.
PUT _transform/odp
{
  "source": {
    "index": "logs-netflow.log*",
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "range": {
              "event.start": {
                "gte": "now-15m",
                "lt": "now"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "terms": {
              "network.iana_number": [17, "17"]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "odp_prep_hscn_netflow_simple_idx"
  },
  "frequency": "5m",
  "sync": {
    "time": {
      "field": "event.start",
      "delay": "1m"
    }
  },
  "pivot": {
    "group_by": {
      "community_id": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "network.community_id"
        }
      },
      "interval": {
        "date_histogram": {
          "field": "event.start",
          "fixed_interval": "5m"
        }
      },
      "source_ip": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "source.ip"
        }
      },
      "destination_ip": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "destination.ip"
        }
      }
    },
    "aggregations": {
      "source_bytes": {
        "sum": {
          "field": "source.bytes"
        }
      },
      "destination_bytes": {
        "bucket_script": {
          "buckets_path": {
            "reverse_source_bytes": "source_bytes"
          },
          "script": """
            // Sum the source.bytes where destination.ip matches source.ip in reverse flows
            return params.reverse_source_bytes != null ? params.reverse_source_bytes : 0;
          """
        }
      },
      "source_packets": {
        "sum": {
          "field": "source.packets"
        }
      },
      "destination_packets": {
        "bucket_script": {
          "buckets_path": {
            "reverse_source_packets": "source_packets"
          },
          "script": """
            // Sum the source.packets where destination.ip matches source.ip in reverse flows
            return params.reverse_source_packets != null ? params.reverse_source_packets : 0;
          """
        }
      },
      "sorted_event": {
        "top_metrics": {
          "metrics": [
            { "field": "event.created", "missing": null },
            { "field": "event.duration", "missing": 0 },
            { "field": "event.ingested", "missing": null },
            { "field": "network.direction", "missing": "unknown" },
            { "field": "agent.name", "missing": "unknown" },
            { "field": "input.type", "missing": "netflow" },
            { "field": "network.transport", "missing": "udp" },
            { "field": "network.iana_number", "missing": 17 },
            { "field": "netflow.ip_class_of_service", "missing": -1 },
            { "field": "netflow.ip_precedence", "missing": -1 },
            { "field": "netflow.exporter.address", "missing": "unknown" },
            { "field": "netflow.ingress_interface", "missing": -1 },
            { "field": "netflow.egress_interface", "missing": -1 },
            { "field": "netflow.icmp_type_ipv4", "missing": -1 },
            { "field": "netflow.icmp_code_ipv4", "missing": -1 },
            { "field": "tcp_control_bits", "missing": 0 },
            { "field": "source.locality", "missing": "internal" },
            { "field": "destination.locality", "missing": "internal" },
            { "field": "source.nat.ip", "missing": "0.0.0.0" },
            { "field": "destination.nat.ip", "missing": "0.0.0.0" },
            { "field": "source.nat.port", "missing": 0 },
            { "field": "destination.nat.port", "missing": 0 },
            { "field": "observer.ip", "missing": "0.0.0.0" },
            { "field": "source.ip", "missing": "0.0.0.0" },
            { "field": "destination.ip", "missing": "0.0.0.0" },
            { "field": "source.port", "missing": null },
            { "field": "destination.port", "missing": null },
            { "field": "tags" },
            { "field": "response_count", "missing": 0 },
            { "field": "source.bytes", "missing": 0 },
            { "field": "destination.bytes", "missing": 0 },
            { "field": "source.packets", "missing": 0 },
            { "field": "destination.packets", "missing": 0 },
            { "field": "netflow.exporter.ip", "missing": null },
            { "field": "netflow.exporter.port", "missing": 0 },
            { "field": "request_count", "missing": 0 },
            { "field": "event.start", "missing": null },
            { "field": "event.end", "missing": null }
          ],
          "sort": [
            {
              "event.start": {
                "order": "desc"
              }
            }
          ],
          "size": 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "docs_per_second": 500000,
    "max_page_search_size": 65535
  }
}

Sample source data

